# If $3x^2\equiv1\bmod p$ then 3 is a quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Unsure of how this implication has occurred. I know that if 3 is a QR then there exists $x^2\equiv3\bmod p$. However, how does this become $3x^2\equiv1\bmod p$?

Comment: Well,  $x^2\equiv 3^{-1}\pmod p\implies x^{-2}\equiv 3 \pmod  p$

Comment: Multiplication by $3$.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer _Right, that's about it..._

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gcd(3,p) = 1$, 3 has a unique multiplicative inverse modulo $p$, say, it is $3^{-1}$. Then original congruence becomes
$$ 3^{-1} \cdot 3 x^2 \equiv 3^{-1} \bmod p.$$
So $3^{-1}$ is a quadratic residue. Then apply
$$ 1 = \left( \frac{1}p\right) = \left( \frac{3}p\right) \left( \frac{3^{-1}}p\right) $$
to get $\left( \frac{3}p\right) = 1$, i.e., 3 is a qudratic residue modulo $p$.

Answer (score 1):

(Franz Lemmermeyer gave this away in the comments)
$$3x^2\equiv1\bmod p$$
$$(3x)^2\equiv3\bmod p$$